# iOS ACAccountStore Save Twitter fails with Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, acaccount, acaccountstore

I am trying to populate and save an ACAccount to ACAccountstore, as follows:

```
ACAccount *account = [[ACAccount alloc]initWithAccountType:twitterAccountType];
                             account.username = @"hansaaaha";

                             while (twitterRequest.rstring == nil)
                             {
                                 continue;
                             }
                             NSString *credentails = twitterRequest.rstring;
                             NSString *oAuthToken = [credentails componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"][0];
                             NSString *oAuthSecret = [credentails componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"][1];
                             oAuthToken = [oAuthToken componentsSeparatedByString:@"="][1];
                             oAuthSecret = [oAuthSecret componentsSeparatedByString:@"="][1];
                             account.credential = [[ACAccountCredential alloc]initWithOAuthToken:oAuthToken tokenSecret:oAuthSecret];

                             [store saveAccount:account withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                                 if (success)
                                     NSLog(@"a");
                                 else
                                     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                             }];
```

Once twitterRequest.rstring (separate thread) is not nil, I get the token and secret.

I probably shouldn't post them in full here, but this is what

> credentials

looks like once it is populated:

> oauth_token=OAtSGoYoXXXXXXXXXXXXXXhtUs4AT&oauth_token_secret=cGFYzLTqxXXXXXXXXXXXbC6JEHtK&oauth_callback_confirmed=true

So after sub stringing, I have

> oAuthToken: OAtSGoYoXXXXXXXXXXXXXXhtUs4AT
>
> oAuthSecret: cGFYzLTqxXXXXXXXXXXXbC6JEHtK

However, saving fails with following error:

> Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)"